# Merge unnecessary partitions on a hard drive (with complications)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, merge

So I have bought this computer with windows 8 pre-installed. When I originally got it on my approximately 1TB HDD, there were a few partitions that did (and still do) things i don't know about. I think its worth mentioning windows 8 is installed using that UEFI mode. So there were only these partitions relevant to this windows 8 installation. After a year or so I upgraded windows 8 to 10 (willingly).

Somewhere along the line, as a programmer I decided I wanted linux ubuntu on my system (dual boot with windows 10). I installed ubuntu, and by doing so i created a bunch of partitions (swap and some others). I think they were required for the installation.

A few months after (it actually worked), I reset windows 10 and the results were a downgrade from windows 10 to 8, and the dual boot gone. By that i mean when i open my computer, it goes straight to windows 8 without giving me the option of selecting linux ubuntu. Furthermore the partitions I created for that installation still remain. So I ended up with partitions that I am not using and are just sitting there, effectively inaccessible.

So what I'd like to do is forget the dual boot, merge all the linux associated partitions with the main C drive and just use windows 8. Problem is i am not sure how do so, and which partitions to mess with, without skrewing up my pc. Here is a screenshot of what my hard disk now looks like. Don't ask me how i got there, I am not sure myself.

[image: Disk management screenshot]

Comment: Please split your text into paragraphs. Use Linux to find out which EFI System Partition is actually in use. // Also, you can’t merge them with C because they are literally at the other end of the disk. Consider merging them with D.

Comment: Okay I am going to try and split the text into paragraphs. Well, merging them with D and then merging D with C is an idea I had. The problem is I can't use linux at all right now, and i don't know which EFI system partition is the one I need.

Comment: You can use a [GParted live USB](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php) to find out what all the partitions are.

Comment: Well I think i know what the major partitions are, but I am not sure if i need the recovery partitions (or how many of them), and what to do with the EFI partitions. Is it safe to delete them? Is it safe to delete the second one? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to reinstall windows 8 and delete all partitions using the installer. There are possible other solutions but this is honestly the easiest for me.

Comment: You could have done the same thing with windows 10 too, or for that matter Ubuntu.